# node-template compilation failed on: sc-network-bitswap v0.10.0-dev

Tags: substrate-node-template

I am following guide at https://docs.substrate.io/quick-start/start-a-node/

```sh
git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template
cd substrate-node-template
git switch -c my-learning-branch-2023-11-10
cargo build --package node-template --release
```

```
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2023-11-10, rust version 1.75.0-nightly (0f44eb32f 2023-11-09)
info: downloading component 'cargo'
info: downloading component 'clippy'
info: downloading component 'rust-analyzer'
info: downloading component 'rust-src'
info: downloading component 'rust-std' for 'wasm32-unknown-unknown'
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
info: downloading component 'rustc'
info: downloading component 'rustc-dev'
info: downloading component 'rustfmt'
info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
info: removing previous version of component 'rust-src'
info: removing previous version of component 'rust-std' for 'wasm32-unknown-unknown'
info: removing previous version of component 'cargo'
info: removing previous version of component 'clippy'
info: removing previous version of component 'rust-docs'
info: removing previous version of component 'rust-std'
info: removing previous version of component 'rustc'
info: removing previous version of component 'rustfmt'
info: installing component 'cargo'
info: installing component 'clippy'
info: installing component 'rust-analyzer'
info: installing component 'rust-src'
info: installing component 'rust-std' for 'wasm32-unknown-unknown'
info: installing component 'rust-std'
info: installing component 'rustc'
info: installing component 'rustc-dev'
info: installing component 'rustfmt'
info: installing component 'rust-docs'
warning: virtual workspace defaulting to `resolver = "1"` despite one or more workspace members being on edition 2021 which implies `resolver = "2"`
note: to keep the current resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "1"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: to use the edition 2021 resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "2"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: for more details see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#resolver-versions
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git`
    Updating crates.io index
... [trim due to 30_000 chars limit]
  Downloaded 400 crates (38.5 MB) in 2m 24s (largest was `librocksdb-sys` at 6.3 MB)
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.66
   Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.11
   Compiling libc v0.2.147
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling version_check v0.9.4
   Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
   Compiling serde v1.0.176
   Compiling serde_derive v1.0.176
   Compiling memchr v2.5.0
   Compiling typenum v1.16.0
   Compiling syn v1.0.109
   Compiling thiserror v1.0.44
   Compiling generic-array v0.14.7
   Compiling once_cell v1.18.0
   Compiling log v0.4.19
   Compiling quote v1.0.32
   Compiling syn v2.0.27
   Compiling subtle v2.4.1
   Compiling bytes v1.4.0
   Compiling jobserver v0.1.26
   Compiling cc v1.0.79
   Compiling getrandom v0.2.10
   Compiling smallvec v1.11.0
   Compiling pin-project-lite v0.2.10
   Compiling futures-core v0.3.28
   Compiling scopeguard v1.2.0
   Compiling futures-sink v0.3.28
   Compiling futures-io v0.3.28
   Compiling num_cpus v1.16.0
   Compiling slab v0.4.8
   Compiling futures-task v0.3.28
   Compiling futures-channel v0.3.28
   Compiling lock_api v0.4.10
   Compiling futures-util v0.3.28
   Compiling byteorder v1.4.3
   Compiling rand_core v0.6.4
   Compiling pin-utils v0.1.0
   Compiling anyhow v1.0.72
   Compiling cpufeatures v0.2.9
   Compiling toml v0.5.11
   Compiling ahash v0.7.6
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.9.8
   Compiling arrayvec v0.7.4
   Compiling ppv-lite86 v0.2.17
   Compiling const-oid v0.9.4
   Compiling indexmap v1.9.3
   Compiling parking_lot v0.12.1
   Compiling rand_chacha v0.3.1
   Compiling tinyvec_macros v0.1.1
   Compiling tinyvec v1.6.0
   Compiling opaque-debug v0.3.0
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.27
   Compiling rand v0.8.5
   Compiling unicode-bidi v0.3.13
   Compiling percent-encoding v2.3.0
   Compiling unicode-normalization v0.1.22
   Compiling form_urlencoded v1.2.0
   Compiling getrandom v0.1.16
   Compiling hashbrown v0.12.3
   Compiling static_assertions v1.1.0
   Compiling crunchy v0.2.2
   Compiling idna v0.4.0
   Compiling arrayref v0.3.7
   Compiling either v1.9.0
   Compiling rand_core v0.5.1
   Compiling url v2.4.0
   Compiling tracing-core v0.1.31
   Compiling keccak v0.1.4
   Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.4
   Compiling constant_time_eq v0.2.6
   Compiling rustix v0.38.4
   Compiling itoa v1.0.9
   Compiling aho-corasick v1.0.2
   Compiling ahash v0.8.3
   Compiling instant v0.1.12
   Compiling regex-syntax v0.7.4
   Compiling blake2b_simd v1.0.1
   Compiling rand_chacha v0.2.2
   Compiling zstd-sys v2.0.8+zstd.1.5.5
   Compiling zeroize_derive v1.4.2
   Compiling thiserror-impl v1.0.44
   Compiling futures-macro v0.3.28
   Compiling tracing-attributes v0.1.26
   Compiling crc32fast v1.3.2
   Compiling rand v0.7.3
   Compiling zeroize v1.6.0
   Compiling regex-automata v0.3.3
   Compiling block-buffer v0.10.4
   Compiling crypto-common v0.1.6
   Compiling proc-macro-crate v1.1.3
   Compiling digest v0.10.7
   Compiling digest v0.9.0
   Compiling sha2 v0.10.7
   Compiling block-buffer v0.9.0
   Compiling sha3 v0.10.8
   Compiling sha2 v0.9.9
   Compiling curve25519-dalek v3.2.0
   Compiling tracing v0.1.37
   Compiling num-traits v0.2.16
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
   Compiling serde_json v1.0.104
   Compiling hashbrown v0.13.2
   Compiling paste v1.0.14
   Compiling regex v1.9.1
   Compiling futures-executor v0.3.28
   Compiling futures v0.3.28
   Compiling parity-scale-codec-derive v3.6.4
   Compiling impl-trait-for-tuples v0.2.2
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling bs58 v0.4.0
   Compiling stable_deref_trait v1.2.0
   Compiling fallible-iterator v0.2.0
   Compiling byte-slice-cast v1.2.2
   Compiling gimli v0.27.3
   Compiling cranelift-entity v0.95.1
   Compiling crossbeam-utils v0.8.16
   Compiling target-lexicon v0.12.10
   Compiling cranelift-isle v0.95.1
   Compiling io-lifetimes v1.0.11
   Compiling cranelift-codegen-shared v0.95.1
   Compiling cranelift-codegen-meta v0.95.1
   Compiling parity-scale-codec v3.6.4
   Compiling ryu v1.0.15
   Compiling bitflags v2.3.3
   Compiling scale-info-derive v2.9.0
   Compiling derive_more v0.99.17
   Compiling wasmparser v0.102.0
   Compiling cranelift-codegen v0.95.1
   Compiling fxhash v0.2.1
   Compiling slice-group-by v0.3.1
   Compiling signature v1.6.4
   Compiling scale-info v2.9.0
   Compiling ed25519 v1.5.3
   Compiling cranelift-bforest v0.95.1
   Compiling regalloc2 v0.6.1
   Compiling object v0.30.4
   Compiling memoffset v0.9.0
   Compiling linux-raw-sys v0.4.3
   Compiling rustix v0.36.15
   Compiling bumpalo v3.13.0
   Compiling sp-std v8.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling base64 v0.13.1
   Compiling ed25519-dalek v1.0.1
   Compiling errno v0.3.1
   Compiling crossbeam-epoch v0.9.15
   Compiling wasmtime-types v8.0.1
   Compiling linux-raw-sys v0.1.4
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.8.6
   Compiling hex v0.4.3
   Compiling rustix v0.37.23
   Compiling wasmtime-environ v8.0.1
   Compiling Inflector v0.11.4
   Compiling itertools v0.10.5
   Compiling memoffset v0.8.0
   Compiling base64 v0.21.2
   Compiling zstd-safe v5.0.2+zstd.1.5.2
   Compiling linux-raw-sys v0.3.8
   Compiling is-terminal v0.4.9
   Compiling wasmtime-runtime v8.0.1
   Compiling generic-array v0.12.4
   Compiling humantime v2.1.0
   Compiling cpp_demangle v0.3.5
   Compiling rustc-demangle v0.1.23
   Compiling termcolor v1.2.0
   Compiling rayon-core v1.11.0
   Compiling env_logger v0.10.0
   Compiling memfd v0.6.3
   Compiling libsecp256k1-core v0.3.0
   Compiling parking_lot v0.11.2
   Compiling crossbeam-deque v0.8.3
   Compiling wasmtime-jit-debug v8.0.1
   Compiling uint v0.9.5
   Compiling crossbeam-channel v0.5.8
   Compiling blake2 v0.10.6
   Compiling bincode v1.3.3
   Compiling psm v0.1.21
   Compiling dirs-sys-next v0.1.2
   Compiling time v0.1.45
   Compiling wasmtime-asm-macros v8.0.1
   Compiling byte-tools v0.3.1
   Compiling wasmtime-cache v8.0.1
   Compiling ref-cast v1.0.19
   Compiling regex-syntax v0.6.29
   Compiling iana-time-zone v0.1.57
   Compiling rustc-hash v1.1.0
   Compiling chrono v0.4.26
   Compiling block-padding v0.1.5
   Compiling cranelift-native v0.95.1
   Compiling cranelift-frontend v0.95.1
   Compiling wasmtime-cranelift-shared v8.0.1
   Compiling directories-next v2.0.0
   Compiling cranelift-wasm v0.95.1
   Compiling regex-automata v0.1.10
   Compiling file-per-thread-logger v0.1.6
   Compiling digest v0.8.1
   Compiling addr2line v0.19.0
   Compiling hmac v0.12.1
   Compiling ref-cast-impl v1.0.19
   Compiling impl-serde v0.4.0
   Compiling wasmtime-jit-icache-coherence v8.0.1
   Compiling wasmtime v8.0.1
   Compiling rustc-hex v2.1.0
   Compiling wasmtime-jit v8.0.1
   Compiling rayon v1.7.0
   Compiling matchers v0.0.1
   Compiling wasmtime-cranelift v8.0.1
   Compiling block-buffer v0.7.3
   Compiling libsecp256k1-gen-ecmult v0.3.0
   Compiling libsecp256k1-gen-genmult v0.3.0
   Compiling tracing-log v0.1.3
   Compiling sharded-slab v0.1.4
   Compiling crypto-mac v0.11.1
   Compiling crypto-mac v0.8.0
   Compiling sp-debug-derive v8.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling tracing-serde v0.1.3
   Compiling secp256k1-sys v0.6.1
   Compiling thread_local v1.1.7
   Compiling ansi_term v0.12.1
   Compiling fake-simd v0.1.2
   Compiling opaque-debug v0.2.3
   Compiling hash-db v0.16.0
   Compiling sp-storage v13.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling sha2 v0.8.2
   Compiling tracing-subscriber v0.2.25
   Compiling hmac v0.8.1
   Compiling libsecp256k1 v0.7.1
   Compiling fixed-hash v0.8.0
   Compiling curve25519-dalek v2.1.3
   Compiling ss58-registry v1.41.0
   Compiling impl-codec v0.6.0
   Compiling merlin v2.0.1
   Compiling rustversion v1.0.14
   Compiling arrayvec v0.5.2
   Compiling environmental v1.1.4
   Compiling sp-externalities v0.19.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling schnorrkel v0.9.1
   Compiling sp-tracing v10.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling primitive-types v0.12.1
   Compiling hmac-drbg v0.3.0
   Compiling hmac v0.11.0
   Compiling pbkdf2 v0.8.0
   Compiling sp-runtime-interface-proc-macro v11.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling pbkdf2 v0.11.0
   Compiling twox-hash v1.6.3
   Compiling dyn-clonable-impl v0.9.0
   Compiling num-format v0.4.4
   Compiling dyn-clone v1.0.12
   Compiling dyn-clonable v0.9.0
   Compiling sp-core-hashing v9.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling tiny-bip39 v1.0.0
   Compiling substrate-bip39 v0.4.4
   Compiling ed25519-zebra v3.1.0
   Compiling bounded-collections v0.1.8
   Compiling hash256-std-hasher v0.15.2
   Compiling secrecy v0.8.0
   Compiling array-bytes v6.1.0
   Compiling nohash-hasher v0.2.0
   Compiling backtrace v0.3.68
   Compiling adler v1.0.2
   Compiling miniz_oxide v0.7.1
   Compiling addr2line v0.20.0
   Compiling object v0.31.1
   Compiling trie-root v0.18.0
   Compiling memory-db v0.32.0
   Compiling trie-db v0.27.1
   Compiling schnellru v0.2.1
   Compiling sp-io v23.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling integer-sqrt v0.1.5
   Compiling sp-arithmetic v16.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling async-trait v0.1.72
   Compiling fnv v1.0.7
   Compiling tokio v1.29.1
   Compiling tokio-macros v2.1.0
   Compiling mio v0.8.8
   Compiling signal-hook-registry v1.4.1
   Compiling sp-panic-handler v8.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling socket2 v0.4.9
   Compiling expander v2.0.0
   Compiling parity-wasm v0.45.0
   Compiling fs-err v2.9.0
   Compiling heck v0.4.1
   Compiling sp-core-hashing-proc-macro v9.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling frame-metadata v16.0.0
   Compiling sp-version-proc-macro v8.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling sp-metadata-ir v0.1.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling sp-api-proc-macro v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling futures-timer v3.0.2
   Compiling proc-macro-error-attr v1.0.4
   Compiling asynchronous-codec v0.6.2
   Compiling proc-macro-error v1.0.4
   Compiling data-encoding v2.4.0
   Compiling unsigned-varint v0.7.1
   Compiling blake3 v1.4.1
   Compiling http v0.2.9
   Compiling synstructure v0.12.6
   Compiling data-encoding-macro-internal v0.1.11
   Compiling constant_time_eq v0.3.0
   Compiling multihash-derive v0.8.1
   Compiling data-encoding-macro v0.1.13
   Compiling blake2s_simd v1.0.1
   Compiling core2 v0.4.0
   Compiling base-x v0.2.11
   Compiling httparse v1.8.0
   Compiling multibase v0.9.1
   Compiling zstd-safe v6.0.6
   Compiling pin-project-internal v1.1.2
   Compiling quick-protobuf v0.8.1
   Compiling ring v0.16.20
   Compiling tokio-util v0.7.8
   Compiling tower-service v0.3.2
   Compiling http-body v0.4.5
   Compiling void v1.0.2
   Compiling try-lock v0.2.4
   Compiling want v0.3.1
   Compiling pin-project v1.1.2
   Compiling h2 v0.3.20
   Compiling rw-stream-sink v0.3.0
   Compiling multistream-select v0.12.1
   Compiling httpdate v1.0.2
   Compiling untrusted v0.7.1
   Compiling prometheus v0.13.3
   Compiling spin v0.5.2
   Compiling semver v1.0.18
   Compiling kvdb v0.13.0
   Compiling vcpkg v0.2.15
   Compiling libz-sys v1.1.12
   Compiling concurrent-queue v2.2.0
   Compiling event-listener v2.5.3
   Compiling wasm-bindgen-shared v0.2.87
   Compiling async-channel v1.9.0
   Compiling sp-database v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling libp2p-swarm-derive v0.32.0
   Compiling wasm-instrument v0.3.0
   Compiling sc-executor-wasmtime v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling flate2 v1.0.26
   Compiling sc-utils v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling hyper v0.14.27
   Compiling netlink-packet-utils v0.5.2
   Compiling sha-1 v0.9.8
   Compiling universal-hash v0.4.1
   Compiling cipher v0.3.0
   Compiling platforms v3.0.2
   Compiling wasm-bindgen-backend v0.2.87
   Compiling soketto v0.7.1
   Compiling netlink-packet-core v0.4.2
   Compiling sct v0.7.0
   Compiling tiny-keccak v2.0.2
   Compiling ipnet v2.8.0
   Compiling proc-macro-hack v0.5.20+deprecated
   Compiling linked-hash-map v0.5.6
   Compiling wasm-bindgen-macro-support v0.2.87
   Compiling netlink-sys v0.8.5
   Compiling wasm-bindgen v0.2.87
   Compiling matches v0.1.10
   Compiling idna v0.2.3
   Compiling substrate-prometheus-endpoint v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling netlink-proto v0.10.0
   Compiling wasm-bindgen-macro v0.2.87
   Compiling curve25519-dalek v4.0.0-rc.1
   Compiling netlink-packet-route v0.12.0
   Compiling polyval v0.5.3
   Compiling webpki v0.22.0
   Compiling rustc_version v0.4.0
   Compiling enum-as-inner v0.5.1
   Compiling nix v0.24.3
   Compiling aead v0.4.3
   Compiling rustls v0.20.8
   Compiling match_cfg v0.1.0
   Compiling hostname v0.3.1
   Compiling trust-dns-proto v0.22.0
   Compiling snow v0.9.2
   Compiling const-random-macro v0.1.15
   Compiling rtnetlink v0.10.1
   Compiling ghash v0.4.4
   Compiling aes v0.7.5
   Compiling ctr v0.8.0
   Compiling chacha20 v0.8.2
   Compiling poly1305 v0.7.2
   Compiling quick-error v1.2.3
   Compiling aes-gcm v0.9.4
   Compiling resolv-conf v0.7.0
   Compiling js-sys v0.3.64
   Compiling chacha20poly1305 v0.9.1
   Compiling lru-cache v0.1.2
   Compiling pin-project-lite v0.1.12
   Compiling quicksink v0.1.2
   Compiling trust-dns-resolver v0.22.0
   Compiling futures-rustls v0.22.2
   Compiling wasm-bindgen-futures v0.4.37
   Compiling webpki-roots v0.22.6
   Compiling quick-protobuf-codec v0.1.0
   Compiling yamux v0.10.2
   Compiling lru v0.10.1
   Compiling x25519-dalek v1.1.1
   Compiling derive-syn-parse v0.1.5
   Compiling if-watch v3.0.1
   Compiling macro_magic_core_macros v0.4.2
   Compiling predicates-core v1.0.6
   Compiling parity-send-wrapper v0.1.0
   Compiling const-random v0.1.15
   Compiling float-cmp v0.9.0
   Compiling der v0.7.7
   Compiling termtree v0.4.1
   Compiling difflib v0.4.0
   Compiling normalize-line-endings v0.3.0
   Compiling macro_magic_core v0.4.2
   Compiling predicates v2.1.5
   Compiling predicates-tree v1.0.9
   Compiling wasm-timer v0.2.5
   Compiling mockall_derive v0.11.4
   Compiling ff v0.13.0
   Compiling downcast v0.11.0
   Compiling fragile v2.0.0
   Compiling base16ct v0.2.0
   Compiling sec1 v0.7.3
   Compiling group v0.13.0
   Compiling macro_magic_macros v0.4.2
   Compiling finality-grandpa v0.16.2
   Compiling crypto-bigint v0.5.2
   Compiling proc-macro-warning v0.4.1
   Compiling spki v0.7.2
   Compiling rfc6979 v0.4.0
   Compiling signature v2.1.0
   Compiling frame-support-procedural-tools-derive v3.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling elliptic-curve v0.13.5
   Compiling ecdsa v0.16.8
   Compiling cfg-expr v0.15.3
   Compiling frame-support-procedural-tools v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling macro_magic v0.4.2
   Compiling fastrand v2.0.0
   Compiling frame-support-procedural v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling mockall v0.11.4
   Compiling k256 v0.13.1
   Compiling tt-call v1.0.9
   Compiling linked_hash_set v0.1.4
   Compiling partial_sort v0.2.0
   Compiling ip_network v0.4.1
   Compiling prost-derive v0.11.9
   Compiling tempfile v3.7.0
   Compiling prettyplease v0.1.25
   Compiling fixedbitset v0.4.2
   Compiling scratch v1.0.7
   Compiling prost v0.11.9
   Compiling glob v0.3.1
   Compiling petgraph v0.6.3
   Compiling prost-types v0.11.9
   Compiling clang-sys v1.6.1
   Compiling which v4.4.0
   Compiling beef v0.5.2
   Compiling link-cplusplus v1.0.9
   Compiling bstr v1.6.0
   Compiling multimap v0.8.3
   Compiling unicode-width v0.1.10
   Compiling tower-layer v0.3.2
   Compiling prettyplease v0.2.12
   Compiling codespan-reporting v0.11.1
   Compiling globset v0.4.12
   Compiling prost-build v0.11.9
   Compiling jsonrpsee-types v0.16.2
   Compiling memmap2 v0.5.10
   Compiling minimal-lexical v0.2.1
   Compiling cxxbridge-flags v1.0.102
   Compiling cxx v1.0.102
   Compiling nom v7.1.3
   Compiling jsonrpsee-core v0.16.2
   Compiling cxx-build v1.0.102
   Compiling tower v0.4.13
   Compiling tokio-stream v0.1.14
   Compiling strum_macros v0.24.3
   Compiling libloading v0.7.4
   Compiling bindgen v0.65.1
   Compiling cexpr v0.6.0
   Compiling jsonrpsee-server v0.16.2
   Compiling jsonrpsee-proc-macros v0.16.2
   Compiling tikv-jemalloc-sys v0.5.3+5.3.0-patched
   Compiling peeking_take_while v0.1.2
   Compiling lazycell v1.3.0
   Compiling shlex v1.1.0
   Compiling jsonrpsee v0.16.2
   Compiling wasm-opt-sys v0.112.0
   Compiling sc-chain-spec-derive v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling lz4-sys v1.9.4
   Compiling cfg_aliases v0.1.1
   Compiling cxxbridge-macro v1.0.102
   Compiling snap v1.1.0
   Compiling wasm-opt-cxx-sys v0.112.0
   Compiling num-integer v0.1.45
   Compiling equivalent v1.0.1
   Compiling bytemuck v1.13.1
   Compiling camino v1.1.6
   Compiling hashbrown v0.14.0
   Compiling safe_arch v0.7.1
   Compiling indexmap v2.0.0
   Compiling static_init_macro v1.0.2
   Compiling serde_spanned v0.6.3
   Compiling toml_datetime v0.6.3
   Compiling fs2 v0.4.3
   Compiling matrixmultiply v0.3.7
   Compiling num-rational v0.4.1
   Compiling winnow v0.5.1
   Compiling utf8parse v0.2.1
   Compiling semver-parser v0.7.0
   Compiling siphasher v0.3.10
   Compiling ucd-trie v0.1.6
   Compiling semver v0.6.0
   Compiling pest v2.7.1
   Compiling anstyle-parse v0.2.1
   Compiling librocksdb-sys v0.11.0+8.1.1
   Compiling wide v0.7.11
   Compiling toml_edit v0.19.14
   Compiling static_init v1.0.3
   Compiling strum v0.24.1
   Compiling sc-network-sync v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling sc-network-light v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling sc-network-bitswap v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling fork-tree v3.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling num-complex v0.4.3
   Compiling approx v0.5.1
   Compiling sc-tracing-proc-macro v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling cargo-platform v0.1.3
   Compiling atty v0.2.14
   Compiling rustls v0.21.5
   Compiling colorchoice v1.0.0
   Compiling rawpointer v0.2.1
   Compiling sc-sysinfo v6.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling anstyle-query v1.0.0
   Compiling anstyle v1.0.1
   Compiling same-file v1.0.6
   Compiling http-range-header v0.3.1
   Compiling walkdir v2.3.3
   Compiling anstream v0.5.0
   Compiling tower-http v0.4.3
   Compiling cargo_metadata v0.15.4
   Compiling simba v0.8.1
error: failed to run custom build command for `sc-network-bitswap v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/jan/git/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/sc-network-bitswap-1b3aa1fed6bfabbf/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at /home/jan/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/prost-build-0.11.9/src/lib.rs:1457:10:
  Could not find `protoc` installation and this build crate cannot proceed without
      this knowledge. If `protoc` is installed and this crate had trouble finding
      it, you can set the `PROTOC` environment variable with the specific path to your
      installed `protoc` binary.If you're on debian, try `apt-get install protobuf-compiler` or download it from https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

  For more information: https://docs.rs/prost-build/#sourcing-protoc

  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

How to proceed?

Comment: Just install protoc

Comment: I think it make sense to improve "Before you begin, verify the following:" section of the guide to mention this OS dependency. @AurevoirXavier any idea where I can submit issue for that?